# I want to display a message just before the last loop happens, saying "This is your last chance"?

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby. I am trying this guessing number game. Everything is well, except for the last part. The user gets 3 chance to guess before the game is over. However; just before the last loop happens, I want to pop a message saying "This is your last chance."

I could not come up with any ideas except for for doing hard coding, where it says if guess == 2 puts "This is your last chance".

```
puts "Please input your name?"
print "> "
name = gets.chomp

puts "\n\n"

puts "Welcome to the Number Guessing Game #{name}."
puts "You have to guess a number between 1 to 10."
puts "You have maximum of three guesses #{name}"

number = rand(10) + 1
puts "Okay I know my number."
puts "Tell me your guess number."

puts "\n\n"

max_chances = 3
guess = 1


while guess_times <= max_chances
    print "Guess number #{guess}: "
    guess_number = gets.chomp.to_i

    if guess_number == number
        puts "Great guess #{name}."
        puts "My number was #{number}"
        # break

    elsif guess == max_chances
        puts "This was your last time"
        puts "My number is #{number}"

    else 
        puts "Sorry that was wrong guess"

    end

    guess_times += 1

end
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything inherently wrong with this.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with hardcoding that since you're comparing a variable to a constant.

Answer (score 1):

This is an possible option among many, splitting code into methods:

```
def get_number(guess_times)
    puts "Guess number #{guess_times}:"
    guess_number = gets.chomp
    # check it's an integer or ask again
    guess_number.to_i
end

def guesses(max_chances, number)
    (1..max_chances).each do |guess_times|
        puts "This is your last chance." if guess_times == max_chances
        guess_number = get_number(guess_times)
        return true if guess_number == number
    end
    false
end
```

Set up the variables:

```
number = rand(1..10)
max_chances = 3
```

Then run

```
puts "Okay I know my number."
puts "Tell me your guess number."
if guesses(max_chances, number)
    puts "Number found it was #{number}"
else
    puts "Wrong. Number was #{number}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your code a bit, with a way you can do what you want. I believe the logic you are looking for is the `guess_times == max_chances - 1` part.
So, if the `max_chances` is 3 you will get a 2 anywhere you use `max_chances - 1`.
Let me know if you have more questions.

```
puts "Welcome to the Number Guessing Game #{name}."
puts "You have to guess a number between 1 to 10."
puts "You have a maximum of three guesses #{name}"

number = rand(10) + 1
puts "Okay I know my number."
puts "Tell me your guess number."

puts "\n\n"

max_chances = 3
guess_times = 1

while guess_times <= max_chances

    print "Guess number #{name}: "
    guess_number = gets.chomp.to_i

    if guess_number == number
        puts "Great guess #{name}."
        puts "My number was #{number}"
        break

    elsif guess_times == max_chances
        puts "This was your last time"
        puts "My number is #{number}"

    elsif guess_times == max_chances - 1
      puts "This is your last chance..."
    else 
        puts "Sorry that was the wrong guess"
    end

    guess_times += 1
end
```

Comment: This was such a small fix. Thanks for it. I think i need to learn to think logically .

Comment: Please mark as the correct answer if you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hash where each key is a number of remaining guesses and the value is the message:

```
wrong_guess_feedback = {
  1 => "This is your last guess!", 2 => "This is your second last guess!"
}
```

Then when you go to print the message, just use the number of remaining guesses to find the matching response.

```
remaining_guesses = max_chances - guess_times
puts wrong_guess_feedback[remaining_guesses]
```

You will probably also want to provide a default message for when no message is found, you can use the `||` operator to do this pretty nicely:

```
remaining_guesses = 99
puts wrong_guess_feedback[remaining_guesses] || "Sorry that was the wrong guess"
```

Comment: This is great idea, but could I ask what happens if guess_time is more than 3 times say 10 times?

Comment: @Niraj check out the last example, if you put 99 or any number that doesn't exist as a key, the hash will return `nil`. Then the `||` operator will return the default `"Sorry that was the wrong guess"`